# How to programmatically check whether temporary materialization occurs

Tags: c++, standards, template-meta-programming

I am wondering, after C++17, is there a way to check whether temporary materialization occurs?
For example, imagine we have a class Foo and we then do something like
`Foo().someFunction()`
in such a scenario Foo() is temporarily materialized to an xvalue. Can I prove (through code) that this indeed happens?

Comment: Just add a `cout` statement inside the `Foo::Foo()` ctor? Other than that i don't think there is a way to "prove" that.

Comment: You can prove materialisation happen on observing the visible side effects of a `Foo` object being constructed – if there are none, why should you even care about? Note that there's an `as if` rule for the compiler: It can do *any* optimisations provided the final resulting code behaves *as if* no optimisations at all would have occurred (with few exceptions e.g. concerning copy elision etc) – this is the colloquial version of the rule, standard is a bit more precise on ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can mark `foo()` with a non-const lvalue ref-qualifier:

```
struct Foo {
   void foo() & { }
};

Foo make() { return Foo(); }

Foo & singleton() { static Foo t; return t; }

void bla() {
    Foo t;
    // "permanent" Foo work
    t.foo();
    singleton().foo();

    // temporary Foo fail to compile
    Foo().foo();
    make().foo();
}
```

Now you get compiler error with temporaries: https://godbolt.org/z/1re8oEE43

Comment: You can probably use an overload to see if it's a temp or not.